# Outer Loop and Inner Loop in Java HashMap

Tags: java, loops, hashmap, nested

I have written below code:

```
for(Long value : hmapA.values()) {
    System.out.println("Value = " + value);
    for (Long value1 : hmapQ.values()) {
        System.out.println("ValueQ = " + value1);
    }
}
```

Inner loop never runs, what could be the reason?

Comment: You need to add more code around how you initializing `hmapQ` variable and populating its values

Comment: `hmapQ` is empty.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that you are referencing different hashmaps (hmapA and hmapQ). If your outer loop runs and the inner doesn't, then the condition of the inner loop is false, which could very well be that hmapQ is empty.

But we would need more of your code to decisively understand the problem.

Comment: No 'could very well be' or 'need more of your code' about it. That is the explanation. No other explanation possible.